# LEAD Tools Example

Tags: c#, ocr

Can somebody show me an example of OCRing using LEADTools version 13 in C#? LEADTools doesn't provide documentations for .NET for version 13. What they have currently is version 16. Thanks.

Comment: I mean the examples are for version 16.

Answer (score 0):

I moved an application from VB6 to VB.Net that used Leadtools, and I had to upgrade to V16 of Leadtools because a few of the functions of V13 would not work under .net. I was not using OCR, but it is most likely the same.